# data analytics / statistics standards or protocols: is there any?

Tags: data-analysis

This is more of an idea than a problem, so I hope I can write a clear question.

I'm working on a web application that will produce several data from its day to day operativity, the nature of which isn't important here.

The application will have to show these data to the administrators, so an analytics section or something like that will be needed, and in fact it wouldn't be too hard to put together something usable.

But, before jumping in on developing that section, a thought arised: I could instead have a separate application, that queries the webapp for its data and does the data analysis.
In this way the analytics application is separate from the main webapp and could be "attached" to other web applications.

A couple of examples:

- from an e-commerce application, the administrators can check the top 10 most sold products or the average income per week;
- from a library application, the administrators can check the books that still haven't been returned or the number of subscribers per month this year.

Data queries can be vary, and hard coding them in the analytics application is fine. The point is if there's any standard or common way to make the datasets available so that another application can query them.

Do you know of any standards or protocols or anything that can guide me in this effort? Is this even feasible, or should each application have its own data analysis part because each set of data is different?

Comment: Where are you planning to store your data? Does the results of your data analysis impact how the webapp operates at run time?

Comment: @user3885927 the data lies within the webapp database (actually it is its live data); no, the results aren't going to impact the webapp operations. I'll add some examples.

Answer (score 1):

The [OData](http://www.odata.org/) protocol is a standard for querying data via HTTP.

Furthermore, I have developed the [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) component. It introduces the concept of cube in a LINQ query and can distribute directly the result of an analysis request as an OData feed.

So you can build a web service that provides, for example, *the top 10 Most products sold per week* via the HTTP request:

```
http://.../analysisService?$select=product,week,quantity&$orderby=quantity desc&$top=10
```

Comment: OData is very interesting. I gave it a two minutes read, but it looks too much overpovered for what I want to accomplish; it looks like it takes a lot to set up everything I need, and this would be for a simple application.

Comment: Ok, I think that OData is too much for me, since the system isn't totally unknown to the data consumers &mdash; I don't need anybody to be able to query the informations (which seems more the type of problem OData is trying to respond to), I'm just looking for a way to partially decouple the data visualization from the application. Thank you for the hint about OData.